# "Unable to connect to server" error during the creation of development graph

Tags: typescript, server, graphql, apollo

i receive this error:
[image]

but the server is started :  "server started at http://localhost:4000/graphql"

this is the code in index.ts :

```
(async () => {
  const app = express();

  const options = await getConnectionOptions(
    process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"
  );
  await createConnection({ ...options, name: "default" });

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [MovieResolver],
      validate: true
    }),
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res })
  });

  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false });
  const port = 4000;
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server started at http://localhost:${port}/graphql`);
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add /graphql at the end,

```
http://localhost:4000/graphql
```

Comment: i tried, nothing change

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: the same error "unable to connect the server "